# PostgreSQL - How to convert seconds in a numeric field to HH:MM:SS

Tags: datetime, postgresql

I'm new to PostgreSQL (I have been using MS SQL for many years) and need to convert a numeric column which contains a time in seconds to HH:MM:SS format.

I have Googled and found that `to_char(interval '1000s', 'HH24:MI:SS')` works so I am attempting to use this with my field name:

`to_char(fieldname, 'HH24:MI:SS')` gives an error `cannot use "S" and "PL"/"MI"/"SG"/"PR"  together`

`to_char(fieldname::interval, 'HH24:MI:SS')` gives an error `cannot cast type numeric to interval`

Can anyone show me where I am going wrong?

Comment: `fieldname` is an integer ? further, what output do you expect if you have an interval bigger than one day ?

Comment: @leonbloy: `HH24` can go beyond 24, despite its name.

Comment: @Quassnoi: Correct. Just wondered if that's  what the poster wanted.

Comment: @leonbloy: yes, it is a numeric(18,0). It is possible for it to be > 24 hours but highly unlikely - it's JIRA work logs I'm looking at

Answer (score 59, accepted):

```
SELECT  TO_CHAR('1000 second'::interval, 'HH24:MI:SS')
```

or, in your case

```
SELECT  TO_CHAR((mycolumn || ' second')::interval, 'HH24:MI:SS')
FROM    mytable
```

Comment: or `mycolumn * '1 second'::interval` which will avoid reparsing the textual format over and over (although it doesn't make much practical difference in this case)

Comment: @Quassnoi is it possible if i will get 1:20:30s then convert into 80:30 please help me

Comment: @AnkitDoshi: please post it as another question.

Comment: The OP didn't ask but if you came here trying to make the same transformation using Redshift, this will work because isn't actually supported.

Comment: For some reason this didn't work for me until I explicitly used a `concat()` on mycolumn and second ... but then perfect so thank you.

Comment: doesnt work for me

Comment: @Mr.P: it does for me

Answer (score 37):

To convert seconds to HH:MM:SS

```
SELECT 120 * interval '1 sec';
```

You will get 00:02:00

To convert minutes to HH:MM:SS

```
SELECT 120 * interval '1 min';
```

You will get 02:00:00