# Convert Minutes to Hours in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Currently having Minutes(`bigint`) as

```
390
```

I want to convert this Minutes to hours. Is there any function to convert it?

```
Eg: 390 as 6.30
```

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2905692/postgresql-how-to-convert-seconds-in-a-numeric-field-to-hhmmss

Comment: Why not just simply divide it with 60? Like `SELECT minutes::numeric / 60`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can have a `PostgreSQL Function` for that,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_min_to_hrs(mins int)
RETURNS numeric AS
$BODY$ 
select  cast(date_part('hours',interval '1 minute' * mins) * 1.0 + 
(date_part('minutes',interval '1 minute' * mins) * .01) as numeric(18,2));
$BODY$
LANGUAGE sql VOLATILE
```

---

```
select fn_min_to_hrs(390)

    Result
+-------------+
|fn_min_to_hrs|
|numeric(18,2)|
+-------------+
|        6.30 |
+-------------+
```

Answer (score 8):

Something like this should work:

```
SELECT  TO_CHAR('390 minute'::interval, 'HH24:MI')...
```

From an answer to a related question: [PostgreSQL - How to convert seconds in a numeric field to HH:MM:SS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2905692/postgresql-how-to-convert-seconds-in-a-numeric-field-to-hhmmss)

Comment: I dont want to convert to char.. Just want to convert my minutes(`bigint`) to hours(`numeric(18,2)`)

Comment: if you want numeric wouldn't 390, be 6.5?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to cast them to an interval and then use date_part to pull out the required fields

```
   select date_part('hours',interval '1 minute' * minutes) as hours,  date_part('minutes',interval '1 minute' * minutes) as minutes;
```

example:

```
dev=# select date_part('hours',interval '1 minute' * 390) as hours, date_part('minutes',interval '1 minute' * 390) as minutes;
 hours | minutes
-------+---------
     6 |      30
```

edit:  in response to other comment..

```
select date_part('hours',interval '1 minute' * minutes) + (date_part('minutes',interval '1 minute' * minutes) * .01);
```

to force it to a numeric.

example:

```
select date_part('hours',interval '1 minute' * 390) + (date_part('minutes',interval '1 minute' * 390) * .01) as foo;
 foo
-----
 6.3
(1 row)
```

cast to numeric

```
select  cast(date_part('hours',interval '1 minute' * 390) * 1.0 + (date_part('minutes',interval '1 minute' * 390) * .01) as numeric(4,2))  as foo;

 foo
------
 6.30
(1 row)
```

or

```
dev=# select  cast(date_part('hours',interval '1 minute' * 240) * 1.0 + (date_part('minutes',interval '1 minute' * 240) * .01) as numeric(4,1))  as foo;
 foo
-----
 4.0
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's even useful for anybody to get 6.30 instead 6.5
but anuway

```
select concat_ws('.', (390/60)::text, (390%60)::text)
```

to get `6.30` as `text`

```
select (390/60.0)
```

to get `6.5` as `float`