# Column in seconds.milliseconds to MIN:SS postgresql

Tags: postgresql, timestamp

I've a column with values in seconds.milliseconds and want to convert it to MI:SS.
How do I do it??

I saw this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2905692/postgresql-how-to-convert-seconds-in-a-numeric-field-to-hhmmss/2905726#2905726) which allowed me to convert when the values were only in seconds.
Expected result: 235.00 = 3.55

I tried doing this:

```
SELECT to_char(mycolumn ||'seconds.milliseconds')::interval 'MI.SS');
```

Doesn't really help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Sexagesimal (base 60) system** ([wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sexagesimal)):

```
SELECT (FLOOR(mycolumn/60) + (mycolumn%60.0)/100) AS mi_ss;
```

where `FLOOR(mycolumn/60)` calculates number of minutes and 
`(mycolumn%60.0)/100` calculates number of seconds with base 60 meaning that `3.55` represents `3` minutes and `55` seconds.

Example:

```
# SELECT (FLOOR(235.00/60) + (235.00%60.0)/100) AS mi_ss;
         mi_ss          
------------------------
 3.55000000000000000000
(1 row)
```

**Decimal time** ([wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_time)):

```
SELECT (FLOOR(mycolumn/60) + FLOOR(100*(mycolumn%60/60))/100)  AS mi_ss;
```

where `FLOOR(mycolumn/60)` calculates number of minutes and 
`FLOOR(100*(mycolumn%60/60))/100` calculates number of seconds with base 100 meaning that `3.50` represents `3` minutes and `30` seconds.

Example:

```
# SELECT (FLOOR(235.00/60) + FLOOR(100*(235.00%60/60))/100) AS mi_ss;
         mi_ss          
------------------------
 3.91000000000000000000
(1 row)
```

Comment: The column values are in the form 235.23. So the answer should be 3.55

Comment: Although the code is appreciated, it should always have an accompanying explanation. This doesn't have to be long but it is expected.

Comment: Explanation:                                                                                                                             Suppose the value is 235.                                                                                                      (235.00/60) will give you 3 and (235.00%60.0) will give you 55. Dividing 55/100 gives .55 and the answer is 3.55!

Answer (score 0):

The answer you linked works just fine:

```sql
SELECT to_char((mycolumn || ' second')::interval, 'MI:SS');
```

Note that `to_char` only prints the given fields. It does not, for example, convert hours to minutes.

```sql
SELECT to_char((3601.1 || ' second')::interval, 'MI:SS');

-- result: '00:01'
```